# Breaking down "also fangen wir an"

Tags: grammar, translation

The meaning of `also fangen wir an`, according to Google Translate is: *let's get started*.

While the individual translation of the words are: *so, catch we, to*.

How did these combine to make that? "So we begin to" with an emphasis because of *wir* after *fangen* instead of before?

Comment: Actually, the word-for-word translation is "so we start/begin". Take a look at [anfangen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anfangen).

Comment: FWIW, "also"  adds some flavor, and the punctuation mark is also relevant. "Also fangen wir an?" I'd translate with "I guess we should get started?" but "Also fangen wir an!" with "(So) Here we go!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here *anfangen* is a so-called "trennbares Verb": it splits into its parts, namely

> *an|fangen* (the whole means *to begin*).

You conjugate the last part. Here it's in imperative mood and therefore *fangen* goes first, then the personal pronoun (*wir*), and finally the first part of the verb (*an*).

---

<sub>I must say I very often hear instead of *fangen* ([ˈfaŋən]), *fangn* ([ˈfaŋn]).</sub>

Comment: I don't understand your statement about pronunciation. Was there a comment which got deleted? Or what are you referring to?

Comment: @Em1 well, when people say *fangen wir an!* I hear nothing between the *ng* (ŋ) and the *n*.  Example: an orchestra conductor.

Comment: True, but still not seeing the relevance. However, your recent edit is wrong ;)

Answer (score 2):

I understand your confusion.
Thats just because of the similitude of two German verbs: *anfangen* which means *to start* or *to begin* and *fangen* which means *to catch.*
Despite their spelling (and etymolgoy), those two verbs have no connection in the German language.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The other answers seem to suggest that they are related. First answerer for example, wrote: "Here anfangen is a so-called "trennbares Verb": it splits into its parts, namely 
an|fangen (the whole means to begin)."

Answer (score 2):

"Fangen" means "to catch" and "an" means "on."

The literaly meaning of "anfangen" is to "catch on" (to something), which is a roundabout way of saying "start."